# Unit tests code with Dns.GetHostEntry(hostNameOrIp) dependency

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependencies

I have code that uses `Dns.GetHostEntry(hostNameOrIp)` and I want to check scenario that one time this function return real values **but** in some time(when I decide) this function throw exception.
Currently I am using MSTest framework in visual studio 2010.
Someone has idea what is the easiest way to achieve it?

Comment: Which test doubling framework do you use? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not using currently mock framework because I read it has problem to mock static classes with non virtual methods...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve it is creating wrapper for this static methods:

```
public class DnsWrapper : IDnsWrapper
{
    public IPHostEntry GetHostEntry(string hostNameOrAddress)
    {
         Dns.GetHostEntry(hostNameOrAddress);
    }
}
```

And make your code depend on this interface:

```
public interface IDnsWrapper
{
   IPHostEntry GetHostEntry(string hostNameOrAddress);
}
```

Now mocking of this dependency is very easy with any mocking library. E.g with [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart):

```
Mock<IDnsWrapper> dnsMock = new Mock<IDnsWrapper>();
dnsMock.Setup(d => d.GetHostEntry(It.IsAny<string>()))
       .Throws(new SocketException());

var yourClass = new YourClass(dnsMock.Object); // inject interface implementation
yourClass.DoSomethingWhichGetHostsEntry();
```

Comment: I don't familiar with moq framework can I change the function behavior in the middle of the unit test? that one time it will not throw exception and one time it will throw exception?

Comment: @ilayzeidman You can definitely do that. Though, I would caution about changing the behavior of a mocked object like this in the middle of a unit test. Rather, you would have multiple unit tests (e.g., one for when the mocked object throws an exception, and one for when it does not).

Comment: @ilayzeidman if parameters of method call are different, then its very easy - just add two setups which accept different parameters, e.g. `Setup(d => d.GetHostEntry("foo")).Returns(...)` and `Setup(d => d.GetHostEntry("bar")).Throws(...)`. But as Lilshieste pointed, consider to create two different tests for that

Comment: In my scenario it is the same parameter (computerName) that the DNS success to resolve and after it can't resolve the same computer name (this is my real scenario that I want to check in development and not in production when some of the users will say there is a bug :)

Comment: @ilayzeidman so, you are resolving same address twice per single method call? My suggestion is just cache host entry returned by first call

Comment: no I am calling the function twice with same parameter in first call I want it to act regular and in second call I want it to throw exception

Comment: @ilayzeidman its very strange requirement, as I already pointed, but also can be done - you can use `Callback` of mock to provide return results manually

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, excuse me. Could you write a little piece of code explaining what you mean with "And make your code depend on this interface", pls?
Thank you very much!